# asynchronous Parse query and tableView display

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, parse-platform

I want to display data from my Parse database with this query method :

```
 //Prepare the query to get all the images in descending order
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BasketballMatch"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        //Everything was correct, put the new objects and load the wall
        self.matches = nil;
        self.matches = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"Parse push %@", self.matches );
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    } else {
        //Show the error
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        [self showErrorView:errorString];
    }
}];
```

and then displaying it with this

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:           (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"match" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"coba dulu %@", [[self.matches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"TeamName"]];

    return cell;
}
```

but the table view cell will show this first

```
cell1 (null)
cell2 (null)
cell3 (null)
cell4 (null)
```

and then a few second later it shows the display what i wanted.

```
cell1 Soccer
cell1 Tennis
cell3 Basketball
cell4 Badminton
```

I want the tableview to display the data I wanted right away. Is there an elegant solution to this...

Comment: What do you return in `numberOfRowsInSection:` ?

Comment: It is also a good idea to set `query.cachePolicy=kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;`